# Error while mounting sinatra application in rails

Tags: mongodb, sinatra, ruby-1.9.2, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-1.8

I have a rails application that in turn uses sinatra app in it. I added this line to routes

```
mount TestApp::Application => "/test_app"
```

now while accessing `/test_app` routes it gives

```
TypeError (no marshal_dump is defined for class Mutex)
```

if ran against Ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.2.1. Sinatra app uses mongo gem.

Now when I run this app against ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.2.1, it gives following error

```
TypeError (can't dump TCPSocket)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you write both apps yourself? What do they do?

Comment: Yes, I did. Both app are normal application. We are reusing sinatra app that was already there. It runs fine standalone.

Comment: can it be a problem with rack-session. I used rack-session in sinatra app `use Rack::Session::Pool, :expire_after => 2592000`

Comment: And are you trying to put mutexes and sockets into it?

Comment: No, I am not using any mutexes and sockets. I tried removing rack-session but no luck

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you've required your TestApp::Application correctly, I think your routes definition should be:

```
match "/test_app", :to => TestApp::Application
```

See [Rails Routing from the Outside in](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-to-rack-applications) for more info.

Comment: Sorry! but this would not server static content from sinatra dir. And FYI `mount TestApp::Application => "/test_app"` is the only way to solve static content problem.

Comment: Seems a bit harsh... you didn't mention static content in your question. How is the above suggestion incorrect? I was under the impression that mount uses match for its routing? [http://living5to9.com/2011/11/rails-routes-match-and-mount](http://living5to9.com/2011/11/rails-routes-match-and-mount/)